# How to select list of list elememts and make different columns in a single dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

```
List1 = [[1,A,!,a],[2,B,@,b],[7,C,&,c],[1,B,@,c],[4,D,#,p]]
```

Output should be like this:

Each different column should contain 1 value of each sublist elements
for example

```
column1:[1,2,7,1,4] 
column2:[A,B,C,B,D]
column3:[!,@,&,@,#]
column4:[a,b,c,c,p]
```

in the same dataframe

Comment: `pandas.DataFrame(List1)`?

Comment: It will consider each sublist as different column, but i want each element of sublist in different columns as mentioned.

Comment: You want 25 columns?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you actually meant for List1 to be this (all elements are strings):

```
list1 = [["1","A","!","a"],["2","B","@","b"],["7","C","&","c"],["1","B","@","c"],["4","D","#","p"]]
```

I don't think that you need to do anything except pass List1 to the DataFrame constructor.  There are several ways to pass information to a DataFrame.  Using lists of lists constructs un-named columns.

```
print(pd.DataFrame(list1))

   0  1  2  3
0  1  A  !  a
1  2  B  @  b
2  7  C  &  c
3  1  B  @  c
4  4  D  #  p
```

Answer (score 1):

Given the below list file:

```
l = [['1', 'A', '!', 'a'], ['2', 'B', '@', 'b'], ['7', 'C', '&', 'c'], ['1', 'B', '@', 'c'], ['4', 'D', '#', 'p']]
```

You can use `pandas.Dataframe` for converting it as below:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.DataFrame(l, columns=['c1', 'c2', 'c3', 'c4'])
# columns parameter for passing customized column names
```

Result:

```
  c1 c2 c3 c4
0  1  A  !  a
1  2  B  @  b
2  7  C  &  c
3  1  B  @  c
4  4  D  #  p
```

Answer (score 0):

As commented (and illustrated by John L.'s answer), `pandas.DataFrame` should be sufficient. If what you actually want is a transposed dataframe, try transpose manually:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame(List1).T
```

Or beforehand using `zip`:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(*List1)))
```

Both of which returns:

```
   0  1  2  3  4
0  1  2  7  1  4
1  A  B  C  B  D
2  !  @  &  @  #
3  a  b  c  c  p
```